# React component props inside nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I am having difficulties understanding how to build a rather simple component that has a variety of props that need to be accessed inside a nested component, within. I don't even know if that is how to correctly explain my situation, regardless I feel like this should be simple.

I'll explain.  I have a  component as follows:

```
<Widget
  layout="small"
  header="This is the header"
  icon={<UploadIcon/>}
  title="This is the title"
  caption="This is the caption to a widget it should have a character count"
  to="/tosomwhere"
  href="http://www.website.com"
  link="Link Title"
/>
```

And the component code.

```
const Widget = (props) => {
  return (
    <WidgetWrapper layout={props.layout}>
      hello world
      {props.title}
    </WidgetWrapper>
  );
}

Widget.propTypes = {
  layout: PropTypes.oneOf(['small', 'large', 'dual']),
  header: PropTypes.string,
  icon: PropTypes.element,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  caption: PropTypes.string,
  to: PropTypes.string,
  href: PropTypes.string,
  link: PropTypes.string,
};

Widget.defaultProps = {
  layout: 'small'
};

export default Widget;
```

As you can see I am including a  component inside the  component.  It's purpose is purely visual (size of widget, color, ext), but it needs to wrap all the props coming from

I can access `props.layout` as it's outside the  component, but I can't access `props.title` inside  that belongs to .

How is this done?  Do I need to pass  props down through  so I can access them that way?  I tried to add a `props={props}` to  with no success...

Comment: If you want to forward all the props to `WidgetWrapper`, you can use `<WidgetWrapper {...props} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should include props like that inside a tag. The way I use to write my React is just pass the props inside the tag like you did with `props.layout`, and then make use of these props inside the code of your `WidgetWrapper`.

Instead of writing every single prop in the tag, you could just use the spreading operator:

```
<WidgetWrapper {...props}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand your problem. Do you want to access some props in Widget component from WidgetWrapper? in this case I think you should pass what you need down. Or do you have many props that you want to pass down to the wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

```
const RenderApp = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      hello {props.title}
    </div>
  );
}



class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (      
        <RenderApp title="world"/>      
    );
  }
}
```

This works for me and prints "hello world"... Maybe I'm missing the point...